# SQL Server: Transfer YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

**My SQL Server system is 2016.**

As topic, I want to convert YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss, and use dynamic SQL to fulfill this.

My data looks like this:

```
      ID
20161119-075950
20161117-110952
20161118-153406
```

The datatype is nvarchar.

While I used the syntax below:

```
SELECT convert(date,convert(varchar(max),id,130), 130) from abc
```

An error **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.** shows up. I am thinking whether it is because SQL Server cannot identify this **YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS** as date type, and I need to convert this to **YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss** first and then **mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss**? Feel free to shed some lights. Thanks!

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired result.  Identify your column types.

Comment: What version of SQL Server is it ?

Comment: Why do you want to use dynamic sql for this? And instead of changing one poor string representation to another you should consider changing the datatype to datetime so this type of thing doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(25) , CAST(LEFT(ID , 8) AS DATETIME), 101) 
       + ' ' +  LEFT(RIGHT(ID , 6) ,2) + ':' 
       + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(ID , 6) , 3,2) + ':' 
       + RIGHT(ID , 2) 
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('20161119-075950')
,('20161117-110952')
,('20161118-153406');
```

--This is the actual `select` you need:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(ID,8) AS DATETIME) + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(ID,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')
FROM @tbl
```

Your first part is strictly 8 chars long and implicitly casteable (unseperated datetime `yyyymmdd`). The time part is strictly 6 chars long. I use `STUFF` to insert the colons. This time can be added to a `DATETIME`. It will be - again implicitly - casted to `DATETIME`.

### EDIT

To reach the given format you stated in the title just convert the first part first with code `101`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(LEFT(ID,8) AS DATETIME),101) + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(ID,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')
FROM @tbl
```

Comment: Your syntax looks good and works. However, I just realized that **Declare** function may not work for Azura under SQL server. It keeps showing an error **Incorrect syntax near 'TABLE'.** So I use **Create Table** instead. At least, now I know **Declare** function is different under Azura.

Comment: @ZedFang Well, the `DECLARE` does nothing else than to define a table as a variable. This will disappear immediately after usage.. Any way you do not need this. It is just to set up a *mock-up* test-scenario...

Comment: Yup, you are right. I think it is not because the server is running under Azura, but the data is in **View**.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the format you want... but there are probably better ways.

```
select 
  convert(varchar(16),convert(date,left(ID,8)),101) + 
  ' ' + 
  substring(substring(ID,10,6),1,2) + 
  ':' + 
  substring(substring(ID,10,6),3,2) + 
  ':' + substring(substring(ID,10,6),5,2)
```